# How to change the interpreter on ipython notebook on AWS cloud

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have recently launched an Ipython notebook cloud on Amazon using the following [link](https://notebookcloud.appspot.com/).

When I try to run the simplest code like:

```
import nltk
```

I get 'nltk' not found error.

or

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0)
```

gives me: `invalid argument min_df` error

I suspect there is some problem with the interpreter associated with the notebook. I would ideally like to switch to Anaconda's interpreter but I don't know how to do that in Ipython Notebook, especially on the cloud as I do not have any kind of access to a server in particular. I can access the notebook ONLY via my browser.

How do I install/change to Anaconda's interpreter using Ipython Notebook via browser?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't change the Python interpreter within the IPython notebook. Whatever interpreter the IPython kernel is running is is set when it starts. You will need to change how you launch IPython so that you load the one from Anaconda and not the other one on the system.

Comment: Understood. But like I said, I don't have any access to the computer itself, all I see is the ipython notebook in my browser. Would you have any siggestions on how to go ahead?